# PHP get current time in option select with cut-off time

Tags: php

I have the following script which works great:

```
<?php
function create_time_range($start, $end, $interval = '30 mins', $format = '12') {
    $startTime = strtotime($start); 
    $endTime   = strtotime($end);
    $returnTimeFormat = ($format == '12')?'g:i:s A':'G:i:s';

    $current   = time(); 
    $addTime   = strtotime('+'.$interval, $current); 
    $diff      = $addTime - $current;

    $times = array(); 
    while ($startTime < $endTime) { 
        $times[] = date($returnTimeFormat, $startTime); 
        $startTime += $diff; 
    } 
    $times[] = date($returnTimeFormat, $startTime); 
    return $times; 
}
$times = create_time_range('7:30', '18:30', '30 mins');
?>

<select name="time_picker">
    <option value="">Select Time</option>
    <?php foreach($times as $key=>$val){ ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $val; ?>"><?php echo $val; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

However I would love to have this altered: First of all it should only show time slots available given my current time, second to include a 2 hour window as "cut-of time".

**Practical example and ideal outcome:** Let's assume it's 1PM, the option select would 1.) not even display the values before 1PM and 2.) only show me the next available slot being 3PM (2 hour window)

I've been struggling with this for a few days but no result at the moment. Some expert advise would be greatly appreciated

http://codepad.org/OT2Qyb00

Comment: You would need to store the times taken already, you can do this in either a database or a textfile on the server, but would use database.

Comment: Can this be done without the use of storing data, meaning server time is being read and only times that fit with the current time being displayed?

Comment: im not sure I understand what you want then, cause this would give all time except what is active atm?

Comment: This current script displays all values from 7:30AM to 18.30PM. My ideal outcome would be the following: Let's assume it's 1PM and I open the page showing this form select. The option select should automatically read the server time and already neglect 7.30AM - 2.30PM as options - it should only show me 3:00 PM - 18.30 PM. I hope that's more clear and thank you very much for your help

Comment: ah, then you can create a time range that is from current + 120 to 18:30. This will then only give you the correct times

Comment: Could you please help me out here by editing my current script? I am not able to get it done. Thank you very much @Simpson

Comment: I've tried your method but it does not seem to work for me - perhaps I am doing it wrong. Your help would be greatly appreciated, thank you

Comment: Well then _show us_ what you tried, otherwise we can’t tell you what you did wrong.

Comment: I've tried both to either change $current   = time();  to $current   = time(+120); and to change $times = create_time_range('8:00', '18:00', '30 mins'); to $times = create_time_range(''.time(+120).'', '18:00', '30 mins'); however ending up in a server error. I've edited my post with a codepad URL

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
<?php
function create_time_range($start, $end, $interval = '30 mins', $format = '12') {
$startTime = strtotime($start); 
$endTime   = strtotime($end);
$returnTimeFormat = ($format == '12')?'g:i A':'G:i';
$hour = date('H');
$minute = (date('i')>30)?'30':'00';
$current = strtotime("$hour:$minute"); 
$addTime   = strtotime('+'.$interval, $current); 
$diff      = $addTime - $current;
$times = array(); 
while ($current < $endTime) { 
    $times[] = date($returnTimeFormat, $current) . " " . "$hour:$minute"; 
    $current += $diff; 
} 
$times[] = date($returnTimeFormat, $current); 
return $times; 
}
$times = create_time_range('8:00', '18:00', '30 mins');
?>

<select name="time_picker">
<option value="">Select Time</option>
<?php foreach($times as $key=>$val){ ?>
<option value="<?php echo $val; ?>"><?php echo $val; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Here I use the $current as a basetime and I create that one by getting current hour and then time rounded by 30 min and then create time from that.

I hope this can help ya.